# get most recent file from azure blob storage

Tags: azure-databricks

My azure blob storage has several files , like

name        last modified
data-GUID1   jan 1,20
data_guid2   jan 2, 20

How would I grab the file   most recent 'last modified' ,like data_guid2 ?

Currently I hard-code the name :

```
 file_location=  /dbfs/mnt/blob/container/data_Guid1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the file names, then write whatever custom code you want to find the most recent (i.e. find the one with the largest number at the end)

You can get this list using the dbutils.fs.ls("") function: https://kb.databricks.com/data-sources/wasb-check-blob-types.html

The url for your block container will have the following format:

```
wasbs://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<file.path>/
```

If you are having trouble with this approach or if you would like to also get the "last modified" timestamps for the files, check out this link for additional ways to list the files in a blob directory: https://kb.databricks.com/data-sources/wasb-check-blob-types.html